# Servidor Proxy Local - C#

Tags: c#, proxy

Recentemente eu tive contato com uma aplicação chamada Burp Suite. A aplicação disponibilizava um servidor proxy local em uma porta específica `(127.0.0.1:8080)`, e, se eu a utilizasse esse servidor proxy no meu browser todas as requisições e as respostas era passadas ao burp suite como um '`middleware`' entre o meu computador e o servidor que eu estava acessando, me permitindo a edição do response antes da renderização pelo browser ou a edição da requisição antes de envia-la. Como eu posso realizar algo parecido no C#?

Comment: Nesse tópico, feito por mim, eu pergunto se é possível e tenho alguma resposta, bem superficial. Neste tópico eu quero saber como fazer realmente isso, lógica, namespaces, entende?

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa, ao invés disso leia o guia [ask] e o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.